# What changed in Burning Wheel between Gold and Revised editions?

Tags: edition-comparison, burning-wheel

What rules changes are there between the *Burning Wheel Gold* and *Revised* editions?

The best answer would be an overview that would give a player familiar with *Burning Wheel Revised* a good sense of where the changes lie and their general nature and intent. I'm not looking for an exhaustive account of the way the rules differ. To put it differently: What are the advantages of playing *Gold* over *Revised*?

Answer (score 7):

You can see for yourself the changes to the "Hub and Spokes" rules, as they are the first 90 pages, and are included in the preview at http://www.burningwheel.org/?p=276. Under the word "Here" in the fourth paragraph on that page is the download link for that preview.

Luke has mentioned that there are numerous small changes to **Fight**, specifically the processes for range setting, **Duel of Wits**, and **Range and Cover**.

Sorcery no longer adds will dice to rolls to cast, reducing the difficulty of advancing Sorcery as one no longer needs insane Obs to get Difficult and Challenging expenses.

Perception is no longer open ended.

Let it Ride drops the bit about referees cheating.

A significant change in terminology: "Graduated Test" replaces the older "Open Test", avoiding the frequent confusion between open ended rolls and open tests.

Some minor changes to the difficulty/test type table at the low end.

Many lifepaths have been revised.

I've not yet gotten BWG yet, only the preview, so I can't be much more detailed, but I'll note that the hub and spokes text is not readily different at first glance, but some small changes are present.

References
http://www.burningwheel.org/forum/showthread.php?11076-Burning-Wheel-Gold-Errors-and-Changes

Comment: Yep, I got the Hubs and Spokes PDF. I'd noticed that the changes aren't readily apparent, and I hadn't had time to go over it with a comb due to multiple persistent interruptions. So, I turned my frustration into a question that I expect will help more than just myself. I expect a full answer will take a while simply because people are still only just getting the preorders in the mail.

Comment: I noticed that help dice can be given for Circles tests.  There are little tweaks to the lifepaths, not to mention the lifepaths' lay-out is cleaner.  I'm reading it cover to cover now and finding little differences: the inclusion of books as learning tools...lots of little things.

Comment: The links in your answer no longer work/point to what they used to.

Answer (score 4):

- Fight! had a major overhaul. Revised tested for position at the start of every volley. Gold effectively tests at the start of each script, and positions last all three volleys unless someone changes weapons.
- Will is no longer added to Sorcery to cast spells, but you can now use FoRKs on Sorcery tests.
- Overall cleanup. Perception is no longer open-ended by default, removing an exception. Better section on BITs, adapted from the Adventure Burner. Open tests renamed to graduated tests, for clarity and to avoid confusion with open-ended. Speed Multiplier was doubled and is now Stride, removing the pesky ".5" for some Stocks.
- Now one hardcover book rather than a pair of softcover books.

Comment: Note that there's now an update to BW Gold called BW Gold Revised. It has a few more cleanups and revision, a more gold cover. It's the Seventh printing of Gold.

Comment: Yep, my BWGR is in the mail. I expect another question for BWG vs. BWGR may become useful soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

The urgency of treating injuries is now measured in sessions or scenes, no longer hours.

I think this is an interesting detail since it represents a move away from concrete fictional measurements of time and toward metagame measurement, which is often more practical in play, once one gets used to it.